# What would these GUI elements represent in MVC terms?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, tkinter

I have a `Listbox` in tkinter in this `Listbox`. We can choose an image, all images are in a array in the model, but I don't known if the `Listbox` corresponds to MVC "View" or a "Controller", and if it's a Controller, how to add an image that we have just imported to it in accordance with MVC.

Comment: What difference does it make to you?

Comment: @martineau if it's a view just need to update width the controler and if it's a controler i'm not supposed to update like a View, i want to respect MVC

Comment: I don't think `tkinter` uses `MVC` - there is only widget which does everything.

Comment: @martineau i know but i want to make my code using MVC and i don't know how to update the controler width MVC

Comment: I think most, if not all, of the widgets that `tkinter` provides would fall into the MVC "View" category. Your array of images sound like a Model (or part of one). The Controller might be 'tkinter' itself. You're mixing apples and oranges, so there's not a perfect mapping from one to the other. Perhaps you should try using [wxPython](https://www.wxpython.org/pages/downloads/) instead, it's very Windows-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Listbox`or any other widget in `tkinter` is both part of the view and part of the controller, in the sense that it is a view (obviously) but it is also acting as a controller when you register callbacks in your code, and the widget catches relevant user interactions (events) and directs them to the registered code (with the help of tkinter event mainloop).

What you can do if you like, is to put your business code in a separated module (your model), make your `tkinter` registered callbacks call the functions in the model, and if the model changes because of that, update the widgets (the view) by notification, using the observer pattern (see a Python example) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Essentially you keep a list of observers in the model, and when the model changes you'll call an `update()` or `notify()` method of them.

That will require you more work, which is a drawback in many cases, but has the power of updating your UI automatically anytime a change in the model affects some widget.

Note that I am not recommending all that work for simple cases (like using a few controls), unless you have good reasons for it. Wanting to use MVC looks like a desire to really separate concerns, but evaluate the effort first...